# ** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to understand the reason behind the crash.

What is `__NSSingleObjectArrayI` ? I couldn't find any information on this.

The crashlog sent by crashlytics is:

```
 Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1836fa1c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18213455c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1836eb428 +[__NSSingleObjectArrayI automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:]
3  boostApp                       0x100070098 -[LocationPromptVc tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (LocationPromptVc.m:269)
4  UIKit                          0x189683078 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
5  UIKit                          0x189733b34 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
6  UIKit                          0x1897e6d5c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
7  UIKit                          0x1897d8b10 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
8  UIKit                          0x189547854 _afterCACommitHandler
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1836a77dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1836a540c __CFRunLoopDoObservers
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1836a589c __CFRunLoopRun
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1835d4048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13 GraphicsServices               0x18505a198 GSEventRunModal
14 UIKit                          0x1895c02fc -[UIApplication _run]
15 UIKit                          0x1895bb034 UIApplicationMain
16 boostApp                       0x1000bbc24 main (main.m:14)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1825b85b8 (Missing)
```

The crash is happening in the below method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //NSArray                //NSArray    both are strong,nonatomic
    self.selectedLocation = self.filteredLocations[indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.searchField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

//datasource method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.filteredLocations.count;
}
```

74% of crashes are happening on iOS10. I have 31 crashes in the past 90 days.

Why is the didSelectRow method pointing to wrong index 18446744073709551615 ?

This crash is very rare, and I'm not able to reproduce it. Any ideas on debugging this ?

The table view is simple.IT has a search field on nav bar, and based on searchfield text,I filter locations and populate the tableview.Once the user select any row, I show the location data on different VC.

Comment: Does the table use self.filteredLocations as the the data for the table, or is it possible that self.filteredLocations might have more objects than the table has rows? or visa versa

Comment: check if the self.filteredLocations.count > indexPath.row and put the code inside this condition. It seems you are trying to get invalid index from array.

Comment: yes, im using the same array as datasource.

Comment: @iProgrammer, if that is the case, then the crash should happen in cellForRow method. Why would didSelectRow return wrong index 18446744073709551615 ?

Comment: `__NSSingleObjectArrayI` is a internal/private cluster for a NSArray containing only one (single) element. That big index may say that it's `NSNotFound` (max integer). Could you tell us more about your tableView?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, I'm sure this happened because you passed a negative number as index in the array. This happened to me once. The large number is -1 expressed as unsigned integer

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri , so the fix is to have a condition check if indexpath.row is always positive ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, `indexpath.row` will never be negative. According to me, that might not be the reason at all. Please check for any array operations in other methods like `_selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:` mentioned in the crash report.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri may be you are altering your datasource or tableview rows. Don't know what are you doing inside your project. Its just one way to debug and avoid crash.

Comment: @Larme , I added the what the table viewVC does.

Comment: I just explicitly convert __NSSingleObjectArrayI to NSArray and everything start working.

Comment: The reason why it could happen is just when your table got an update right after user pressed a cell: 1) User presses cell, 2) Updated (refresh comes) 3) Since there's no cell user pressed on, indexPath for it <-1,-1>

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.. May this code will help. In my application I am also getting the same crash for collectionView and its very rare. Its a purely indexOutOfBounds issue. I dont know how come my collectionView showing more items than datasource count. But conditional check helps me and now my app is not crashing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //NSArray                //NSArray    both are strong,nonatomic
    if (self.filteredLocations.count > indexPath.row && indexPath.row >= 0) {
      self.selectedLocation = self.filteredLocations[indexPath.row];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
      [self.searchField resignFirstResponder];
  }
}
```