# Unable to get the reason for crash log: IOS app crash when initially launched

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

My app is working fine for every device and simulator me and my testers checked with. but it crashed for a specific user. I got the crash log from his device but couldn't understand the reason for crash.

Here is my Crash Log:

```
Date/Time:           2018-07-25 11:41:53.4778 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-07-25 11:41:49.3381 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Baseband Version:    1.93.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x184786d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1839405ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18471fd80 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 127
3   UIKit                           0x18ecfdaa8 -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 171
4   UIKit                           0x18ea160f4 -[UITableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 67
5   UIKit                           0x18e4600cc -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 667
6   UIKit                           0x18e45fd84 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 79
7   UIKit                           0x18e45eaa0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2279
8   UIKit                           0x18e45a5ec -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 139
9   UIKit                           0x18e3976f4 -[UIView+ 308980 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1419
10  QuartzCore                      0x18890dfec -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 183
11  QuartzCore                      0x18891217c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1208700 (CA::Transaction*) + 323
12  QuartzCore                      0x18887e830 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 604208 (CA::Transaction*) + 319
13  QuartzCore                      0x1888a6364 CA::Transaction::commit+ 766820 () + 579
14  UIKit                           0x18e655598 _afterCACommitHandler + 255
15  CoreFoundation                  0x18472e910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 31
16  CoreFoundation                  0x18472c238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 411
17  CoreFoundation                  0x18472c884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1435
18  CoreFoundation                  0x18464cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
19  GraphicsServices                0x186631020 GSEventRunModal + 99
20  UIKit                           0x18e669758 UIApplicationMain + 235
21  Visits                          0x1021b5418 main + 21528 (Location+CoreDataClass.swift:15)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x1840ddfc0 start + 3
```

And (Location+CoreDataClass.swift:15) file has following code

```
10 import Foundation
11 import CoreData
12 import CoreLocation
13
14 @objc(Location)
15 public class Location: NSManagedObject {
16    
17    @objc var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
18        get{
19            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
20        }
21    }
```

Code for my tableView datasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultController.sections?[section] else {
        return 0
    }
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultController.sections else{
        return 0
    }
    return sections.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: visitCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Need to know the reason of crash. I have been testing this app for more than a month but haven't got this crash. But this user is not even able to start the app.

Comment: App Crashed in cellForRow of tableview and reason may be your array in your Visits class

Comment: seems to be an array index out of bounds crash. Check is there any scenario  the data source for your tableview may contain less than the number of  items expected

Comment: maybe this can help you [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536276/how-to-diagnose-exc-crash)

Comment: put a break point at [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath] ans check your datasource array count and cell index, and  array value .

Comment: I have two tableViews in my app.
One is using fetchedResultsController as data source and other one doesn't have a data source since it is a static tableView and designed in Interface builder.

Comment: Your crash log similar to this. It has few solution follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663384/nssingleobjectarrayi-objectatindex-index-18446744073709551615-beyond-b)

Comment: @vivekDas I am not able to replicate this crash. The app is working fine for me. Even after reinstalling the app.

Comment: If you are not able to reproduce the crash, for now you can put a condition as IndexPath.row < YourArray.count before accessing the dataSource array.

Comment: @vivekDas I am using a FetchedResultsController and I added the code for my datasource.

Comment: Can you provide your [configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath)] method to check.

Comment: @vivekDas If it was a problem with configure cell, It would appear in backtrace.

Comment: Seems your fetchedResultsController data source fetching from coredata the data is not proper or index is out of bound. Check your DB table data and count.

Comment: Assuming that cellForIndexPath is returning nil.. 
Seems that function tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: visitCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) is the only line which can return nil, 
but I have my cell registered with cell identifier. Any idea in which other case it can return nil?